# Can I generate Switch Cases with a For loop?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Bear in mind that I am probably going about this the wrong way, so if there is an easier way to do this please let me know.

I have an array:

```
state: string;
states = [
    {name: 'Arizona', code: 'AZ', active: true},
    {name: 'California', code: 'CA', active: false},
    {name: 'Colorado', code: 'CO', active: false}
  ];
```

I am using a `<select>` element to select `<option>`s using `*ngFor="let state of states"`, but I am also wanting to set the `[select]` attribute to whichever is selected.

I am thinking of using a `switch` statement to test whether each state is set and returning true as to activate the `[selected]` attribute. However, I was wondering if it would be possible to use a `for` loop within the `switch` to actually generate the `case` options?

Such as:

```
switchMe(name: string) {
    switch(name) {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.states.length; i++) {
        case this.states[i].name:
          return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

Otherwise, my switch would look something like this:

```
switchMe(name: string) {
        switch(name) {
          case 'Arizona':
          case 'California':
          case 'Colorado':
             return true;
        }
      }
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-switch-selected)

Comment: You can set the selected property just fine with ngFor

Comment: @Luca Could you please give me an example?

Comment: If you share the code you are currently using to generate the select, I'll give you an example ;-)

Comment: @LucaKiebel - Updated with a stackblitz for you :-)

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you're looking for. Is this a multiple select? A single select? There are a number of questions about selecting options in selects in both circumstances: [Angular2: how bind to select multiple](//stackoverflow.com/q/35167463) and [assign select initial value in angular4](//stackoverflow.com/q/46782231)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just set the `select` attribute to `state.active`, like so:

```
<select>
  <option disabled>Make selection</option>
  <option value={{state.name}} *ngFor="let state of states" [selected]="state.active||false">
    {{state.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Stackblitz Link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-switch-selected-lysrup?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: I know that this works for this example. What about if there were no 'active' property?

Comment: I think I actually solved it with `switchMe(name: string) {
    return this.state === name;
  }`

Comment: You can just use `state.active||false` instead